Is there a formula for the number of isomers given n carbon atoms?
I saw the following list of alkanes along with the number of isomers they have on Wikipedia:

C1: 1
C2: 1
C3: 1
C4: 2
C5: 3
C6: 5
C7: 9
C8: 18
C9: 35
C10: 75
C12: 355
C32: 27,711,253,769
C60: 22,158,734,535,770,411,074,184 isomers

If you are unfamiliar with what an isomer is, look it up. Given n carbon atoms, is there a formula for how many isomers this carbon would have? This question is purely mathematical so I'd ignore any weird chemistry effects. I don't know where to begin since there isn't a clear pattern.

https://oeis.org/A000602?

@HackR The OEIS description is in terms of quartic trees, so  I assume it omits cycloalkanes. And the agreement of OEIS with OP's computations suggests that OP also omits cycloalkanes.

My question asks for a formula
